# Remove a line from a file based on serial number?

Tags: bash

I have this file here below here:

```
#12345 Saab 1998 Red
#54321 Volvo 1990 Grey
#45678 Citroen 2004 Yellow
```

If I want to remove a line by serial #54321 or #12345?
What should I do to remove a line by the serial number?

Comment: I have tried sed command but haven't succeed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep` for this:

```
grep -E -v "#12345|#54321"
```

which means the following:

```
grep -E : use extended regular expressions (different items, separated by "|")
-v      : instead of showing the matching lines, show the ones which don't match.
```

Comment: How can i overwrite the file?

Comment: You can't overwrite the existing file, you need to use an intermediate file and afterwards, you can overwrite the original file with the intermediate one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` to remove a line that matches a given pattern (e.g. #54321) from a given file and update/modify it at the same time (`-i` arg) like this:

```
sed -i '/#54321/d' file.txt
```